# html scrollable area define scrolled position

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I have the following scrollable area, the html (using ember, so written using hbs) receives the selected div in the scrollable area, and it colors the selected div in gray. (code below).

Here is how the div looks like:
[image]

here is the html (hbs)

```
<div role="listbox" style="overflow-y: auto">
  {{#each @variables as |var|}}
    <div class="variable-row  {{if (eq var @selectedVar) "selected-row"}}">
      {{var}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.selected-row {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

my issue is when the `selectedVar` isn't seen (for example var under `kkkk` needs to be scrolled to be seen)
is there anyway I can tell the html to scrolled down to the `selectedVar`? something like below, or maybe by adding some css?

```
            {{#each @variables as |var|}}
                <div {{if (eq var @selectedVar) "scroll-to-this-element"}}>
                    {{var}}
                </div>
            {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple options

- render with a selector, and use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
- call a function from the template directly via modifier, also using [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) -- this has the advantage of being reactive

### Calling a function

```
{{#each @variables as |var|}}
  <div data-selected={{ (eq var @selectedVar) }}>
    {{var}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

and then in your js, if you happen to have a good time to call this function

```
scrollSelectedIntoView() {
  document.querySelector('[data-selected]').scrollIntoView();
}
```

### Using a modifier

see: https://github.com/ember-modifier/ember-modifier

```
{{#each @variables as |var|}}
  <div {{if (eq var @selectedVar) this.scrollIntoView}}>
    {{var}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

```
import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';

// ...

scrollIntoView = modifier((element) => {
  element.scrollIntoView();
});
```

This will scroll your list when `@selectedVar` changes as well

Comment: I tried this: `<div {{if (eq var @selectedVar) this.scrollIntoView}}>` but I get this error on compiling:
`The 'if' keyword was used incorrectly. It was used as a modifier, but its valid usages are: - As an expression, as in: (if)

- As an append statement, as in: {{if}}

- As a block statement, as in: {{#if}}{{/if}}
`

Comment: first method (Calling a function) works well, thanks!

Comment: are you using at least ember-source 3.28?

Comment: yes,  ember-cli: 3.28.5

Comment: that's not ember-source, what's your ember-source version?

Comment: `3.28.9` (output for typing `Ember.VERSION` in the browser running my ember app)

Comment: oh, you may need to wrap your helper invocation in parens